# how start a route in a Camel test with mocked Endpoints

Tags: java, cxf, apache-camel

I'm starting out with Camel and I'm having some problems writing a test. My use case is exactly the same as the [cfx proxy example](http://camel.apache.org/cxf-proxy-example.html). Except that I don't need the "RealWebservice". Now I'm trying to write a unit test (not an integration test as included with the example), using the annotation approach:

```
@RunWith(CamelSpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath:application-context.xml" })
@MockEndpointsAndSkip
public class RoutesTest {

@Autowired
CamelContext camelContext;

@EndpointInject(uri = "mock:cxf:bean:cxfEndpoint", context = "camelContext")
MockEndpoint cxfEndpoint;

@EndpointInject(uri = "mock:log:input", context = "camelContext")
MockEndpoint logInputEndpoint;

@EndpointInject(uri = "mock:http:realhostname:8211/service", context = "camelContext")
MockEndpoint realEndpoint;

@EndpointInject(uri = "mock:cxf:bean:cxfEndpoint")
ProducerTemplate producer;

@Test
public void testLeleuxMifidRoute() throws InterruptedException {
    String body = "<blah/>";

    cxfEndpoint.expectedBodiesReceived(body);
    logInputEndpoint.expectedBodiesReceived(body);
    realEndpoint.expectedBodiesReceived(body);

    producer.sendBody(body);

    MockEndpoint.assertIsSatisfied(camelContext);
}
}
```

The cxfEndpoint receives the message **but the other endpoints don't.**

The route looks like this (it works when I run it and send a message with SoapUI, obviously I obfuscated the ips and beannames in this example):

```
<endpoint id="callRealWebService" uri="http://realhostname:8211/service?throwExceptionOnFailure=true" /> 
<route>
  <from uri="cxf:bean:cxfEndpoint?dataFormat=MESSAGE"/>
  <to uri="log:input?showStreams=true"/>
  <to ref="callRealWebService"/>
  <to uri="log:output"/>
</route>
```

What am I doing wrong? All the examples and other questions I found seem to use "direct:start" or change the production route.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One approach that we used with success is to have different properties files for test execution and for the main code.

We define, inside the camel-context, the property

```
<propertyPlaceholder id="properties"
            location="classpath:META-INF/uri.properties" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring" />
```

In the folder `/src/main/resources/META-INF/` we have the uri.properties file for the main code and `/src/test/resources/META-INF/` we have the uri.properties for the test execution.

Your route has to be rewritten using property placeholder instead of the real uri values, using the notation `{{properties.name}}`

```
<route>
  <from uri="{{cxf.bean.cxfEndpoint}}"/>
</route>
```

the main uri.properties will be

```
cxf.bean.cxfEndpoint=cxf:bean:cxfEndpoint?dataFormat=MESSAGE
```

the test uri.properties will be

```
cxf.bean.cxfEndpoint=direct:start
```

Using this configuration, you'll be able to test your route easily.